# kendo UI ignores fixed header

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have the following problem. I'm currently building a onepager dashboarding page with the kendo framework but I have the following problem. All the kendo widgets ignore my fixed header and are floating on my page.

You can find an example on this url:
[enter link description here](http://cedric.yourhostmanager.com/bigpicture/#dashboardresultaatpage)

If you scroll above you will see that my kendo widgets (window, charts) are floating above my navigation. I looked for hours to find the right css prop to disable that, but didn't find it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are Kendo Windows and not Kendo Panels. Panels are decoration of an HTML element and they do not float. Windows is much more than that and float in front of others elements, that's why they are called *windows*.

A panel is the following HTML:

```
<div id="panel" class="k-block">
     <div class="k-header">Header</div>
     Block with header
</div>
```

You can find more panel styling here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styling/panels